# how do I append readAsBinaryString or readAsDataURL to FormData

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, filereader, form-data

I have this normal file upload, but what do I need is to send a file stored as a string in local storage along with FormData, because I cannot change anything on server. I will store the file locally using readAsBinaryString or readAsDataURL .

```
var reader = new FileReader();
/**
File reading code
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);    
**/
var fileString = reader.result
```

I need to send fileString into below formData.append instead of the imagefile.files[0]

Any idea?

```
var formData = new FormData();
var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
axios.post('upload_file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata

Comment: thanks so much, it looks like it will work, trying that..